# URLのクエリパラメーターについて

Tags: url

クエリパラメーターを使用する際に、一つのパラメーターに複数の検索条件をつけたい場合ってどうリクエストを送るのが正解なんでしょうか？

`https://localhost:8080/hoge?fuga=aaa&fuga=bbb&fuga=ccc`

このように書くのが正解ですか？
他に記述方法があれば教えていただきたいです。

Comment: 正解か不正解かはサーバー側でそれを受け取る側の仕様次第です。そこをはっきりさせてもらえないと話が始まらないと思いますが？

Comment: こんな記事も参考になるかもしれません。[パラメータとクエリ文字列の使用に関するREST API設計の最適プラクティス](https://itnews.org/news_contents/rest-api-design-best-practices-for-parameters-and-query-string-usage), [\[RESTful API\]パスパラメータ、クエリパラメータ、リクエストボディの違いと設計](https://qiita.com/Shokorep/items/b7697a146cbb1c3e9f0b)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

API設計がどのようになっているのか分からないので、明確な回答が出来ませんが、カンマ区切りで送ってバックエンドで処理すればいいのではないでしょうか？？

```
URL?search=hoge,foo,123
```